# Custom Post Type URL rewrite with Post Type Template

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

I am building a Wordpress site for a video production company. They produce videos for adults as well as for kids and therefore I split the posts in the backend to keep a structure. So the setup is the following:

- Two Custom Post Types named *productions_big* and *productions_small*
- A page named *Productions*, placed in the main navigation with links to
  *For Big* and *For Small* pages
- One page listing the posts of *productions_big*, one listing posts of
  *productions_small*. The page names are *for-big* and *for-small* and both are children of the *Productions* page
- The URLs are perfectly fine for the pages as I made a parent/child relation of the relevant pages. *example.com/productions* leads to the right page as well as *example.com/productions/for-big* and *example.com/productions/for-small* do.
- For reasons that are irrelevant to this question the templates for
  the CPTs differ, but in some occasions template-big is used for productions_small and vice versa. There is no actual logic behind this and therefore the decision on which template to use is done in the backend via the [Post Type Template](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/11/03/post-type-templates-in-4-7/) feature introduced with Wordpress 4.7

What I want to achieve is a logical URL structure like *example.com/productions/for-big/name-of-adult-production*. Right now I have URLs like *example.com/productions_big/name-of-adult-production* as productions_big is the name of the CPT.

I am familiar with the **rewrite** argument you should pass when registering custom post types. I have done this in all the ways suggested at stackoverflow but it is just not working. Here is an excerpt of the code I use to register my CPTs:

```
add_action('init', 'all_custom_post_types');

function all_custom_post_types() {

  $types = array(

    array('the_type' => 'productions_big',
                ...

    array('the_type' => 'productions_small',
                ...

);

  foreach ($types as $type) {

  $the_type = $type['the_type'];
    ...

  $args = array(
    'labels'        => $labels,
    'public'        => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'       => true,
    'query_var'     => true,
    'rewrite'       => true,
    'capabilities'  => array(
      ...),
    'rewrite'       => array('has_archive' => false, 'slug' => 'bla', 'with_front' => false),
    'has_archive'   => false,
    'map_meta_cap'  => true,
    'hierarchical'  => false,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'supports'      => array('title','editor','thumbnail', 'taxonomies'),
    'taxonomies'    => array( 'category' )
  );

    register_post_type($the_type, $args);

  }

}
```

As you see I tried *'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'bla')* because I wanted to know if it does not work because of a conflict of page names when I write *'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'productions/for-big')*

But whatever value I give the slug, it always redirects me to *index.php*.

I thought the reason why it is not working is caused by the way I am assigning post templates (remember: as a post attribute in the backend, not a dedicated *single-xxx.php* file) but I couldn't find a solution anywhere. All solution-seekers posting their questions were assigning templates the good old fashioned *single-name_of_cpt.php* way (which is not possible for me).

Sidenote: The ultimate goal would be to make the slug "dynamic". Meaning that it changes in case the page names are altered in the backend. I might try [this approach](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36017/custom-slug-for-custom-post-type) but beforehand I'll have to get rid of the basic problems described here.

Any idea is much appreciated. And thank you for reading this far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh boy, seems you have to post your questions in order to find an answer yourself. After trying to setup another CPT everything worked like a charm.

That made me investigate the registration of the previous CPTs. As you can see above I tried to register my CPTs inside of **one** function

```
function all_custom_post_types() {

  $types = array(
    array('the_type' => 'productions_big', ...
    array('the_type' => 'productions_small', ...
  );

  foreach ($types as $type) {

  $args = array(...
    'rewrite'       => array('slug' => 'bla'),...
  );

  register_post_type($the_type, $args);

  }

}
```

So ultimately there was no conflict between the slugs of my pages and custom post types but a conflict of giving one and the same slug to two different post types.